# How to initiate SLO request using Sustainsys

Tags: asp.net-core, saml, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

Trying to get the Single Log out request working with Okta

I've tried using the Sample code on Sustainsys as below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

    _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");

    return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        RedirectUri = "/Index"
    },
    Saml2Defaults.Scheme);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to call the Single Log Out. I just get redirected to my Logged Out page. From what I've read it is supported so not sure what I should be calling. In startup I load the metadata which has the SLO url in it so it should know where to be pointing.

Okta requires a cert so I've added the associated pfx file in my startup like so:

```
        // Add Saml Athentication
        var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication();
        authBuilder.AddSaml2(options =>
        {
            // SAML Okta options
            options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId(Configuration["SAML:AudienceURI"]);

            // Set up redirect to SAML controller callback to handle log in after SAML Authentication (For Okta/IDP initiated log in)
            options.SPOptions.ReturnUrl = new Uri(Configuration["SAML:ReturnURL"]);

            // Scheme to handle the authentication
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            options.SignOutScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;

            // Set up Identity Provider
            var identityProvider = new IdentityProvider(
                new EntityId(Configuration["SAML:EntityID"]),
                options.SPOptions)
            {
                Binding = Saml2BindingType.HttpRedirect,
                LoadMetadata = true,
                MetadataLocation = Configuration["SAML:MetadataURL"],
                AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true
            };

            options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("Okta.pfx", ""));
            options.IdentityProviders.Add(identityProvider);
        });
```

Any ideas? Do I have to do it manually? If so, any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Okay must have missed this but the answer is to just redirect to /Saml2/Logout

This still isn't working as the claims needed for logout aren't present but that this step may help someone.

Comment: You can both redirect to /Saml/Logout or use SignOut. But if the necessary requirements are not present none will work.

Answer (score 0):

For single logout to work there are a number of requirements that need to be present.

There is a logging message written at https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/74045327e15812c60610746bd0632f1f9236b5bd/Sustainsys.Saml2/WebSSO/LogOutCommand.cs#L175 that will indicate the status of the requirements before deciding whether to do a federated single logout or not.

```
options.SPOptions.Logger.WriteVerbose("Initiating logout, checking requirements for federated logout"
+ "\n  Issuer of LogoutNameIdentifier claim (should be Idp entity id): " + idpEntityId
+ "\n  Issuer is a known Idp: " + knownIdp
+ "\n  Session index claim (should have a value): " + sessionIndexClaim
+ "\n  Idp has SingleLogoutServiceUrl: " + idp?.SingleLogoutServiceUrl?.OriginalString
+ "\n  There is a signingCertificate in SPOptions: " + (options.SPOptions.SigningServiceCertificate != null)
+ "\n  Idp configured to DisableOutboundLogoutRequests (should be false): " + idp?.DisableOutboundLogoutRequests);
```

In Asp.Net Core a non-federated logout is a no-op - the Asp.Net core model is that the application needs to both signout the federation scheme and the session authentication scheme.

Comment: Hello @Anders, How to inject these data before logout from External Provider, because the user want to roll back the registration, all data are nulls

=============================
Initiating logout, checking requirements for federated logout
  Issuer of LogoutNameIdentifier claim (should be Idp entity id):
  Issuer is a known Idp: False
  Session index claim (should have a value):
  Idp has SingleLogoutServiceUrl:
  There is a signingCertificate in SPOptions: True
  Idp configured to DisableOutboundLogoutRequests (should be false):
=========================